# How do I fill an image as a background in android using xml while maintaining the aspect ratio?

Tags: android

How do I fill an image as a background in android; similar to filling  an image as a windows background?

That is to say, I want to image to be stretched/shrunk to fit the background, but maintain its aspect ratio cropping sides equivalently if needed.  Is this possible?

For example, if I have an 800x800 image which I use as a background. If it is loaded onto a 320x240 device, then the image should be shrank to 320x320 and used as a background cropping 40 from each side on the short edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your800by800background">
        ... Layout Items ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Where linear layout is your root layout element.

Comment: wouldn't the aspect ratio of the image be changed if the device isn't square?

Comment: Oh probably.  All of the backgrounds I've used seem to scale elegantly.  I am pretty sure there are some settings you can apply to your drawable that will cause it to crop.  Your best bet is most likely to handle it programatically by loading the bitmap and scaling it appropriately.